# Both OpenSSH v5.3 (yum) OpenSSH 7.5 (manually installed) are coexisting, need to remove v5.3 properly

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have both OpenSSH v5.3 (yum) OpenSSH 7.5 (manually installed) via configure/make compiling on GNU/Linux.

`sshd` is showing v7.5 as running and everything is working just dandy.  It would appear that when I try to remove v5.3 via:

`rpm -e openssh*`.

That it breaks the OpenSSH installation completely and ssh is no longer working.   So I'm assuming that the v7.5 and v5.3 files are merged somehow.  So anyone of the following scenario's played out will be fine with me:

- Is there a way to have yum show that I'm on v7.5?
- Is there a way to
  remove v5.3?

When I search the hard drive for configuration files. I have two distinct locations:

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

`/usr/local/etc/sshd_config`

But I know `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is where the active configuration is reading from.  Not sure what the other location is doing if anything?

Comment: How did you manually installed the OpenSSH 7.5? How do they coexist?

Comment: so v5.3 was already installed via yum.   I downloaded v7.5 directly from OpenSSH.com, untar'd it, ran `./configure`, ran `make` then `make install`.

Comment: Well, then 7.5 was installed to `/usr/local/` and by removing the 5.3 package you miss a lot of glue that is provided by the RHEL/CentOS package. Getting this work is over the format of the answer here. If you wish to use new version, you should update your system to RHEL7/Fedora.

Comment: Just to reiterate, I'm on Oracle Linux 6.7.   So what your saying, I should upgrade to Oracle Linux v7 ?  (latest stable OpenSSH is v6.6 for Oracle Linux v7)

Comment: It would be much easier and less painful way to get new openssh

Answer (score 0):

When you ran `rpm -e openssh*` you told it to erase all packages with names beginning "openssh", meaning you uninstalled both.

Go ahead and reinstall v7.5 and you'll be good to go.

As for config, global configuration will be pulled from `/etc` by default so this behaviour is expected. `/usr/local/etc` is used for user-centric configurations. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15473/what-is-the-difference-between-etc-and-usr-local-etc) for a good description of the difference between `/etc` and `/usr/local/etc`.

Comment: I'm testing in on a sandbox server which is a VM.  So I reverted back to my snapshot and I'm back at where I started (v5.3 & v7.5). :)

sooooo... from this point, how can I do it so I'm only on v7.5?  (also, erasing everything made me lose connectivity to my server complete, I also couldn't log in via console)  Thankfully, snapshot saved me.

Comment: Type `rpm -e openssh` and hit tab a couple of times and see what autocomplete suggests. If it specifically has `openssh5.3` and `openssh7.5` then complete with 5.3 and run

Comment: Sooo, from reading that it looks like Openssh 7.5 still depends on some of 5.3's packages.

Comment: I tried posting a comment show what happened and it ended up so messy. :(

Essentially, it only shows v5.3.  Recall v7.5 was installed from the source, so rpm/yum doesn't know about it.  Hence my conundrum.

@I_GNU_it_all_along   Exactly.

Comment: Yep, I saw the comment. As said, from what you posted it looked like 7.5 depends on a couple of parts of 5.3 but I'm not too sure...